# Using beautiful soup to access specific div tag when two div tags have similar class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the titles and their associated links from a website: https://www.mmh.com/search/results/search?channel=content

In it the article name(in the "h2" tag) and the link, are present in a `div` tag with the
`class="col-md-6"`. However as it turns out there is another `div` tag with a similar class name called
`class="col-md-6 left"`.

Whenever I try using `soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col-md-6'})`, it for some reason refers to both of these classes mentioned instead of only accessing the class `'col-md-6'`, and I am unable to figure how to uniquely only access that first specific class.

You can assume the structure of the site to be of this sort:

```
<div class="class="col-md-6 left" style="float: left;">
    ....
    ...
    ...
</div>

<div class="class="col-md-6 left" style="padding-right:30px;">
    <a href="link1"></a>
    <h2> Title1</h2>

    <a href="link1"></a>
    <h2> Title2</h2>

    ... .... ...
</div>
```

This is what i have currently done in my solution. I have created a dictionary called "titleLinks" in order to store the article title and its corresponding URL.

As of now it gives an error to me saying:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` when I try calling the line `title = row.find("h2").text`, which is because the tag does not exist in the first `div` tag with `class="col-md-6 left"`

```
def get_links():

    titleLinks={}
    url='https://www.mmh.com/search/results/search?channel=content'


    user_agents_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36'
    ]

    
    get_link = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agents_list)})
    get_link_text = get_link.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_link_text,'html.parser')

    
    for row in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col-md-6'}):
        print(row)
        title = row.find("h2").text
        link = row.find("a").get("href")
        titleLinks[title].append(link)
    
    print(titleLinks)

get_links()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting that data you're after (first 10 pages) -- you can functionalize it if you want. :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using Jupyter notebook, do from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_list = []
for page in tqdm(range(0, 10*12, 12)):
    url = f'https://www.mmh.com/search/results/search/P{page}?channel=content'

    soup = bs(s.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

    titles = soup.select('a[href^="/article/"]')
    for t in titles:
        big_list.append((t.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '), 'https://www.mmh.com' + t.get('href')))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(big_list)), columns=['title', 'link'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
10/10 [00:17<00:00, 1.75s/it]
    title   link
0   Concentric acquires Hawaii-based Industrial Battery Solutions   https://www.mmh.com/article/concentric_acquires_hawaii_based_industrial_battery_solutions
1   Inside the Parts Town fulfillment center: Built for simplicity, speed and growth    https://www.mmh.com/article/inside_the_parts_town_fulfillment_center_built_for_simplicity_speed_and_growth
2   Top 20 materials handling systems suppliers 2023    https://www.mmh.com/article/top_20_warehouse_automation_and_automated_materials_handling_systems_suppliers_2023
3   ELTEN expands central warehouse capacities in Germany   https://www.mmh.com/article/elten_expands_central_warehouse_capacities_in_germany
4   Demand for warehouse automation soars   https://www.mmh.com/article/promat_c_suite_interview_with_andrea_pongolini_of_e80_group
...     ...     ...
134     Read more   https://www.mmh.com/article/building_and_maintaining_your_maintenance_repair_and_operations_mro_tech_wo
135     Blue Yonder research: supply chain executives turn to technology amid prolonged challenges  https://www.mmh.com/article/blue_yonder_research_supply_chain_executives_turn_to_technology_amid_prolonged_challenges
136     Lift truck computing: Practicality reigns supreme   https://www.mmh.com/article/lift_truck_computing_practicality_reigns_supreme
137     EPG appoints new CEO for Americas   https://www.mmh.com/article/epg_appoints_new_ceo_for_americas
138     Depalletizing and palletizing gain in flexibility   https://www.mmh.com/article/depalletizing_and_palletizing_gain_in_flexibility

139 rows × 2 columns
```

See documentation for Requests [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and also for [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Comment: Hey, so this solution does work but i am unable to understand how your soup.select('a[href^="/article/"]') statement is working. I have never used .select so it seems confusing to me the formatting

Comment: It works by selecting links where the `href` attribute starts with `/article/` -- the `^` means 'starts with'.

Comment: Hi, i was just observing the data, and noticed it is getting the data from the latest resources section at the bottom which is not something i want the data to have. Additionally, all of it seems to be out of order and very randomised.

This is especially unhelpful since i am trying to get articles and the default description given only up to a certain date. This is why i requested on how do i fix my method. could you please check?

Comment: My answer addressed your question `as asked`. Your comment sounds like a new issue altogether. You want the dates as well? Those can also be extracted along with links, however -- not part of your original question. If you think you can unaccept answers on a whim and still receive (unpaid) help, good luck to you. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.